# Proper way to present popup or presentVC (timing)

Tags: ios, popup, alert, presentviewcontroller

I am doing a bit of checks in my `viewDidLoad` such as

1. Internet availability
2. Location service enabled,
3. Logged in?

All of which includes pop ups or performing `segue` or presenting VC if condition are not met.

I came to realise that, it is bad to do any of that in `viewDidLoad` because I can not guarantee whether or not the `view` has appeared.

I was wondering, what is the standard way to ensure popUps and/or views are displayed at the right time?

1. Move everything relating to checks to `viewDidAppear` (That would be most of my code in `viewDidLoad`)
2. A convenient way to let the code know to present the VC/popup if the view has appeared otherwise wait for it to appear than present it (Some sort of function?)
3. Other???

Comment: Option 1 seems proper. Just make sure it is only the initial call to `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: you can use `dispatch_once` in `viewDidAppear` which will allow you to execute only once.

Comment: That seems good. But does that essentially slow down the process because the code only runs when the screen is fully shown (lets say transition time is 0.4 seconds + viewDidLoad time + some other time).  What I was trying to do before was to have everything in viewDidLoad but have flags that lets viewDidAppear to know what to display when that code runs. But it becomes really messy and bad because for slow network connection, viewDidAppear will run first before any flag was set